# SQL Server: What's the Difference Between a 'Singleton Lookup' and a 'User Lookup'?

Tags: sql-server, index, index-statistics

Microsoft describes the `[user_lookup]` counter in `dm_db_index_usage_stats` as the 'Number of bookmark lookups by user queries.'  It describes the `[singleton_lookup_count]` in `dm_db_index_operational_stats` as the 'Cumulative count of single row retrievals from the index or heap.'  This is not at all clarifying to me.  Could someone provide a clearer definition/differentiation of what these two values are tracking?

The question stems from an index observation (800m row table) today where the current `[user_lookup]` value on the Cx was around 800 and the `[singleton_lookup_count]` was over 1 billion.  They're obviously counting much different things and I need to understand what they are and whether a difference of that magnitude could be indicative of a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These counters are not always easy to interpret for reasons I will explain shortly. They can be useful as a indicator there might be areas you need to analyse in more detail.

> The question stems from an index observation (800m row table) today where the current [user_lookup] value on the Cx was around 800 and the [singleton_lookup_count] was over 1 billion.

The `user_lookup` value means a bookmark lookup operator (*Key* or *RID Lookup*) accessing the clustered index or heap appeared 800 times in executed plans.

The `singleton_lookup_count` value includes the number of rows looked up using the *Key* or *RID Lookup* operators. It **also** counts every *guaranteed* single-row access to the clustered index that is **not a lookup**. This occurs when the clustered index is unique, and one or more equality seek predicates are used.

A *singleton lookup* is a b-tree traversal guaranteed to find at most a single matching record. This is the case for each seek-able equality predicate applied to a unique index.

For example, `select id from table where id in (1, 2, 3, 4)` results in four *singleton lookups* if `id` is a unique index key and an index seek is used. Note, no bookmark lookup is used.

A *Key* or *RID Lookup* is nothing more than a unique index seek using an equality predicate, so they're counted the same.

A lookup is always to a unique 'index' even if the base table is a heap or the clustered index is not unique. In the case of a heap, the *unique row locator* is the heap RID. For a non-unique clustered index, the *unique row locator* is the clustered index key(s) plus any 'uniquifier' (present for actually duplicate keys only).

#### Index Usage Stats

The index usage stats DMV contains counts of index operations from the perspective of the **Query Executor** (QE). This is the SQL Server component responsible for executing the query plan.

| name | description |
| --- | --- |
| user_seeks | Number of times an Index Seek operator appears in an executed plan. |
| user_scans | Number of times a Table Scan or Index Scan operator appears in an executed plan. |
| user_lookups | Number of times an RID or Key Lookup operator appears in an executed plan. |

The way these counters are incremented is not entirely intuitive:

- An operator is counted *once* per plan execution.
- Generating an estimated plan does not affect the totals.
- An *Index Seek* that executes 10,000 times in a single plan execution still only adds 1 to the count of user seeks.
- An operator is counted *even if it is not executed at all*.

#### Index Operational Stats

The index operational stats DMV contains counts of index and table operations from the perspective of the **Storage Engine** (SE).

| name | description |
| --- | --- |
| range_scan_count | Number of range scans (including unrestricted full scans) on a heap or index structure. |
| singleton_lookup_count | Number of singleton lookups in a heap or index structure. |

This DMV counts each storage engine operation, making the counters perhaps more intuitive:

- 10,000 singleton lookups will add 10,000 to the *singleton lookup* count column
- A table scan that is executed 5 times will add 5 to the *range scan* count.

---

For examples showing when each counter is incremented, see my article [Seeking Without Indexes](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/02/seeking-without-indexes.html).

Answer (score 3):

In general terms, this is the same type of information as collected in
the column `user_lookups` in `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`. There is a significant
difference, though, between `user_lookups` and `singleton_lookup_count`. When a key
lookup is used, `user_lookups` will increment by one to indicate that the index operation had been used. With `singleton_lookup_count`, for every row that uses the key lookup operation, the value in this column will increase by one.